# Why is it token undefined?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am getting token undefined whenever I create a new user through my front-end. Through my back-end, I check through Insomnia, and I can create a user and get a token perfectly fine. I am using React - is there something wrong with my code?

Here is the code to my signup page:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

function SignUpPage()  {


    const [register, setRegister] = useState({
        username: "",
        charity_name:"",
        charity_abn:"",
        email:"",
        password: "",
        about: "",

    });

    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const handleChange = (event) => {
        const { id, value } = event.target;
        setRegister((prevRegister) => ({
            ...prevRegister,
            [id]: value,}));
        };

        const handleSubmit = (event) => {
            event.preventDefault();
            if (register.username && register.password) {
               postData().then((response) => {
                window.localStorage.setItem("token", response.token);
                navigate("/");
               });
            }
        }

    const postData = async () => {
        const response = await fetch(
            `${import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL}users/`,
            {
                method: "post",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(register),
            }
        );
        return response.json();

        
    }
    return (
           
            <form className='form-wrapper'>
                <div className='title-form'>
                    <h1>Sign Up</h1>
                </div>
                <div className="username">
                    <label htmlFor="username">Username:</label>
                    <input type="text" onChange={handleChange} id="username" placeholder="Username"/>
                </div>
                <div className="charity_name">
                    <label htmlFor="charity_name">Charity Name</label>
                    <input type="text" onChange={handleChange} id="charity name" placeholder="Charity Name"/>
                </div>
                <div className="charity_abn">
                    <label htmlFor="charity_abn">Charity ABN</label>
                    <input type="number" onChange={handleChange} id="charity abn" placeholder="Charity ABN"/>
                </div>
                <div className="email">
                    <label htmlFor="email">Email:</label>
                    <input type="email" onChange={handleChange} id="email" placeholder="email"/>
                </div>
                <div className="password">
                    <label htmlFor="password">Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" onChange={handleChange} id="password" placeholder="password"/>
                </div>
                <button className="primary-button" onClick={handleSubmit} type="submit">Sign up</button>
                </form>
    )

}

export default SignUpPage;
```

I tried to console.log(token) but it says that the token does not exist.

*Edit - I just noticed that when I try to GET token (api-token-auth/) from Insomnia, it's a 405 error saying "Method "GET" not allowed." Would this be the reason why?

Comment: Where exactly are you trying to log `token`?

Comment: Hi, this a sign-up form for a new user. When a new users signs up, I want it to create a token for them so that they are authenticated to explore the rest of the site.

Comment: Yes, but where are you trying to log the value?

Comment: Did you mean to use `console.log(localStorage.getItem('token'))`?

Comment: I used console.log(localStorage.getItem('token')) here -

const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
            event.preventDefault();
            {
               postData().then((response) => {
                window.localStorage.setItem("token", response.token);
                console.log(localStorage.getItem('token'))
                navigate("/");
               });
            }
        }

however I am getting 'undefined'..